# What to do deal with the alert when installing an enterprise app?

Tags: ios, enterprise

When I touch the button to install it will show a alertView which says
`XXXXX would like to install "My App Name"`. 
One is `Cancel` and the other is `Install`. 
Is it possible to know which action I have choose? Because I want to popAction when tap `Cancel` and back to the phone homeScreen (I don't know whether it is possible) when tap `Install`.

[image: the UIAlertView after I touch the updateButton]

Comment: I think there is no option to do so

Comment: Operating system? version? distribution?  Specific application as they all act a little differently depending on how and who packaged them.

Comment: When I tap the `Install` it begin, but it still in my app. People who don't know tapping the homeButton probable think something wrong with my app...

Comment: Are you talking about managed devices? Then probably yes, otherwise no way! Please give some details ...

Comment: @dogsgod The UIAlertView is made by system not my idea, so I cannot set the delegate. I have insert a picture. Please refresh.

Comment: I thought so. The question is still: how do you distribute the app? Do you have managed devices? A store? Or via download/iTunes?

Comment: I put myApp.ipa on my service, then I request a html to install. I have join the enterprise program so I need not to manage devices.

Answer (score 0):

The alert is presented by the operating system.  If the user selects "Cancel" then your app isn't installed and so it isn't possible for your app to perform any actions - it isn't on the device.